# Jenkins Android unit test path showing up twice under /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/

Tags: android, unit-testing, jenkins

So I have assets that my android unit tests are depending on, and in my gradle config file, I have the following lines:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/androidTest/assets']
    }
```

When I ran the test, I get get the java.io.FileNotFoundException. And the weird thing is that the path showing next shows the home dir of my test showing up twice, example here:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/homedir/homedir/src/androidTest/assets/example.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Of course it will throw this exception, because it is under /homedir/src, not /homedir/homedir/src. Anyone know why it is using the double path?

Comment: It seems that when run from the command line, like Jenkins, the path is included as you found. But if run from Android Studio, it is not.  It's nice to be able to run it both ways...  Still fiddling to see if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Gradle automatically appends the included dir in the file settings.gradle, and in my test code I have test dir hard coded as well. Fixed it by taking out the hard coded path in my own unit test.